# How to set alertdialog box title for different buttons ?

Tags: android, button

I'm using same alertdialog box for three buttons (clothing, acessories, shoes ). Is there any way - when click on `button clothing` the dialog box pop up with `title clothing` and respectively for all other buttons.
By default `alert dialog box title is button label` as defined in code `dialog.setTitle("Button label")`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == clothing){
        mDialog();
    }
    if(v == acessories) {
        mDialog();
    }
    if(v == shoes){
        mDialog();
    }}

public mDialog(){
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
 dialog.setTitle("Button label");
 dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
 dialog.setMessage("click ok to close ");
 dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 });
 dialog.show();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the Button label to method `mDialog` ... and in `mDialog` method at `setTitle` just pass the `string`.

```
mDialog(button.getText().toString);
```

In method use like this:

```
public mDialog(String name){
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
 dialog.setTitle(name);
```

Comment: this help a lot. Can you also tell me how to delete these button programatically

Comment: Instead set your `button` to `invisible`.....
`myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == clothing){
        mDialog("clothing");
    }
    if(v == acessories) {
        mDialog("acessories");
    }
    if(v == shoes){
        mDialog("shoes");
    }}
```

pass your string that you want to mDialog ,and for `mDialog`:

```
public mDialog(String title){
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
 dialog.setTitle(title);
 dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
 dialog.setMessage("click ok to close ");
 dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 });
 dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNegativeButton%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) or [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) or any other similar.

Simply while building a dialog add parameters that you need. Don't do it at dialog.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).--build methods--.create();
```